# Click loop until the (button) element found for multiple buttons in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click the 'Followed' button until it found in the web page.

I've below code:

```
@Test
public void testCar() throws Exception 
{
    driver.get("https://-----/login/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("user");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Followed']")).click();
}
```

How can I do this? if not found the element then click next page & find the button again.

here is the next button HTML:

```
<span>Next Page</span>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a loop around with try catch

```
try {
  while (true)
  {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Followed']")).click();
  }
} catch (ElementNotFoundException ex) {
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Next Page']")).click()
}
```

If the element is found it will be clicked, if not then a element not found exception will be thrown and that time you can click on the Next page button

Comment: Thanks, In next page how do i search the 'Followed' Button again.

Comment: Put the code i wrote in another while. And catch the exception when NextPage click fails

Answer (score 0):

Check the condition weather **Followed** button available or not for that you have to use List to get followed webelements Like :

```
Boolean buttonNotFound = true;

while(buttonNotFound)
{
    List<WebElement> follow = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[text()='Followed']"));       
    if(follow.size()!=0)
    {
            follow.get(0).click();
            buttonNotFound=false;
    }
    else
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Next Page']")).click();
    }
}
```

**NOTE :** Don't write `ImplicitWait` again and again, If you have mentioned at one place right below the `get()` then it is applicable for whole script. If some element require some more time to interact then use `ExplicitWait`.